# deduct 30 minutes from shift time

Tags: excel, vba

could you give me code to deduct "00:30:00" from shift timings (e.g. 5:00:00) and store in another variable.
The shift time will be get from input box.
Addition gives correct answer (5:30:00) where as deduction gives like 0.528999 etc.

```
  If shin2 <> "" Then
  intime2 = TimeValue(shin2) + TimeValue("00:30:00")
  MsgBox intime2
  intime22 = TimeValue(shin2) - TimeValue("00:30:00")
  MsgBox intime22
  End If
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you paste the code that you're currently using?

Comment: Thanks friend for your commitment.  here is the code where + works perfectly, -ve gives wrong answer.If shin2 <> "" Then
    intime2 = TimeValue(shin2) + TimeValue("00:30:00")
      MsgBox intime2
      intime22 = TimeValue(shin2) - TimeValue("00:30:00")
      MsgBox intime22
      End If

Comment: Do you declare your variables? What are intime2 and intime22 declared as?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub SHIFTTIME()
    Dim t As Date, s As String
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter time as hh:mm:ss", Type:=2)
    t = TimeValue(s) - TimeSerial(0, 30, 0)
    MsgBox t
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it looks ok to me.

```
Sub TimeValueTest()

Dim shin2 As String
Dim intime22 As Double, intime2 As Double


 shin2 = InputBox("Enter time in hh:mm:ss format")

 If shin2 <> "" Then
  intime2 = TimeValue(shin2) + TimeValue("00:30:00")

  Debug.Print "intime2"
  Debug.Print "value: " & intime2
  Debug.Print "time: " & Format(intime2, "hh:mm:ss")
  Debug.Print "----"

  intime22 = TimeValue(shin2) - TimeValue("00:30:00")

  Debug.Print "intime22"
  Debug.Print "value: " & intime22
  Debug.Print "time: " & Format(intime22, "hh:mm:ss")
  End If


End Sub
```

Outputs the below, if I enter 05:00:00 into the inputbox.

```
intime2
value: 0.229166666666667
time: 05:30:00
----
intime22
value: 0.1875
time: 04:30:00
```

Under the bonnet TimeValue converts a time string to a decimal number, so I suspect that your strange result may have something to do with your variables and how they are declared.